# Securing communication between desktop app and web api

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl, asp.net-web-api, tls1.2

I am developing a desktop app in .net using wpf. This app will consume some web apis on my website using proper authentication using tokens. I am using httpclient for this communication and this is working as expected.

I am now looking to secure the communication channel to avoid data interpretation by middleman, somewhat in the same way a browser encrypts using ssl certificate.

Tried searching on Google and SO but couldn’t find something useful except using a web browser inside desktop app, which I do not want to do. Please help me find the right direction to proceed.

Comment: `HttpClient` supports mutual SSL/TLS. Learn about it further and you should see how to.

Comment: Use a certificate to encrypt webapI data is a good choice for protecting the communication.
 https is http with SSL which supports the X509 authentication with a certificate. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api

Comment: @Abraham Qian, SSL is alreay enabled on server and browser requests are already being served at https. The concern is about sending request from Desktop app to Web API. I am reading more about it as suggested by Lex Li and will post an update if I find something useful.